# rpart summary: missing variables in plot

Tags: r, decision-tree, rpart

I have a dataset with 9 features, from `x1` to `x9`. Target variable is `Target` (I have a classification problem). The code:

```
# Splitting the dataset into the Training set and Test set
# install.packages('caTools')
library(caTools)
set.seed(123)
split = sample.split(dataset$Target, SplitRatio = 0.75)
training_set = subset(dataset, split == TRUE)
test_set = subset(dataset, split == FALSE)

training_set[-c(2,5)] = scale(training_set[-c(2,5)])
test_set[-c(2,5)] = scale(test_set[-c(2,5)])


# Fitting Decision Tree Classification to the Training set
# install.packages('rpart')
library(rpart)
classifier = rpart(formula = Target ~ .,
                   data = training_set)

# Predicting the Test set results
y_pred = predict(classifier, newdata = test_set[-2], type = 'class')

# Making the Confusion Matrix
cm = table(test_set[, 2], y_pred)

plot(classifier, uniform=TRUE,margin=0.2)
text(classifier)
```

produces:

[image]

Anyway, I see 7 variables sorted by importance. The first question is: why only 7 (they are 9)?

```
summary(classifier)


Variable importance
x7 x6 x4 x1 x3 x2 x5 
27 18 17 14 11  9  4
```

Moreover (this is the second questions) `x3` is missing in the plot. Why?

The dataset is too big and I think I can't put it here, but I wanted to know if something similar has happened to you and if you have found any possible explanations.

Thank you!

Comment: It will be difficult to give a specific answer without more details about the structure of `dataset` : factors, continuous variables, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the tree-building process in the `rpart` algorithm. See [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rpart/vignettes/longintro.pdf) for an in-deep explanation with some real case study examples. However, the tree is built by the following process: first, the single variable is found which "best"
splits the data into two groups. The data is separated, and then this process is applied *separately* to each sub-group, and so on recursively until the subgroups either reach a minimum size or until no improvement can be made. So this means that some variables can be excluded from the final model.

Furthermore,

> The cp option of the summary function instructs it to prune the printout, but it does not prune the tree. For each node up to 5 surrogate splits (default) will be printed, but only those whose utility is greater than the baseline “go with the majority” surrogate.

I think this could explain the missing `x3` predictor